# transaction are still pending

Tags: transactions

in ethereum based private network, transaction are still pending.
why this transaction does not complete ?
below is information dumped from the console.

```
txpool.inspect
{
  pending: {
    0x5Cf70Fa5984683659dd661A4408C807a02C318C1: {
      0: "0x960b8fEc9f9C909878aC651113f833E99242338f: 50000000000000000000 wei + 121000 gas × 18000000000 wei"
    }
  },
  queued: {}
}

txpool.content
0: {
        blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        blockNumber: null,
        from: "0x5cf70fa5984683659dd661a4408c807a02c318c1",
        gas: "0x1d8a8",
        gasPrice: "0x430e23400",
        hash: "0xae26b46b73a0f9ee1da088bc66dc092a297584302a40cc3d2cf33e23b0833cee",
        input: "0x",
        nonce: "0x0",
        r: "0x9bdeaddaf2056a886b66b62e388cb1f3935c9cf4f003516607676681bc17caa4",
        s: "0x250109163780fd123258f20068f6f1a98224802f16b64585832aa6e5d83ad0",
        to: "0x960b8fec9f9c909878ac651113f833e99242338f",
        transactionIndex: "0x0",
        v: "0x3c30",
        value: "0x2b5e3af16b1880000"
      },
```

Comment: how are you running your private network ?

Comment: Since nonce is zero it is the first transaction from that account. One possibility is the balance in that account is not enough to pay for the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

This is **porbably** due to `nonce` problems and synchronization between the RPC caller and the geth node. If you are trying to send many transactions in a short time, this is likely to happen.

**EDIT :**

If you try and send many transactions without managing `nonce` yourself in a short amount of time, it is possible that a transaction gets sent with the same , higher or less `nonce` as a previous one which will cause the previous transaction to stay in the tx pool for ever or get refuted. The miss calculation of nonce is due to `web3` nonce guessing mechanism or any other framework that does that.

An other point : If you don't run any miner ( or any kind of block maker ) node within your network, you will not be able to make any blocks. So the transactions stay in the `txpool` untill they get mined ( when a miner or maker node joins in )

Comment: can you go into more depth on your comment above regarding whether it is a private blockchain?
if so, do you know what parameter is causing the bottleneck?